# How to store the matched condition in a variable which can be clicked using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a value in excel and checking the existence in array of elements in drop down. Where the condition passes, I want to store that and click. I tried to store it in a string but, it is not clickable. I tried to store in a web element but failed. kindly help.

```
List<WebElement> countrylist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li label[for*='ddlBU'] span"));
List<String> all_countrylist = new ArrayList<>();
Thread.sleep(1000);
String selectedcountry = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/ul/li[2]/label/span")).getText();
WebElement clickselectedcountry = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/ul/li[2]/label/span"));
Thread.sleep(1000);
for(int cui = 0; cui < countrylist.size(); cui++)
{
    all_countrylist.add(countrylist.get(cui).getText());
    if((countrylist.get(cui).getText()).equalsIgnoreCase(countrysheet.getCell(0, 2).getContents()))
    {
        System.out.println("the Country " + (countrysheet.getCell(0, 2).getContents()) + " which is existing"); 
        String clickcountry = (countrylist.get(cui).getText());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nSelected Country " + (countrysheet.getCell(0, 2).getContents()) + " which is not existing"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the error message that you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
 String countryToBeSelected = countrysheet.getCell(0, 2).getContents();

 By selectedCountryLocator = By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/ul/li[2]/label/span");

 String selectedcountry=driver.findElement(selectedCountryLocator).getText();

 //If Country is other than selected country, then click and open the list 
 if(!countryToBeSelected.equals(selectedcountry)){
        WebElement clickselectedcountry=driver.findElement(selectedCountryLocator);
        clickselectedcountry.click();

        //Get List Of All Countries In WebElement List
        List<WebElement> countrylist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li label[for*='ddlBU'] span"));

        //Store all country details in list
        List<String> all_countrylist=new ArrayList<String>();

        //Iterate over WebElement list and store country values in string list
        for(WebElement country : countrylist){
            all_countrylist.add(country.getText());
        }

        //Get the expected country index
        int elementIndex = all_countrylist.indexOf(countryToBeSelected);

        //Click on After finding the Country Index
        countrylist.get(elementIndex).click();

 }
```

Comment: its jumping to out of the loop after if condition. the below stmt not executed - WebElement clickselectedcountry=driver.findElement(selectedCountryLocator);
            clickselectedcountry.click(); but the values are same in the If condition. it says "WebElement clickselectedcountry cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: I believe if the country to be selected and country that is already selected, then no need to select the country. That's why it's not executing the statement under if. But if the country to be selected and country that already selected is different then it will open the dropdown values by clicking on selected country and iterate over all elements and match the expected value and click.

Comment: no, if the condition matches then only I will have to select that particular country. I have tried this: if ((countrylist.get(cui).getText()).equalsIgnoreCase(countrysheet.getCell(0, 2).getContents()))
   {
    
    System.out.println("the Country " +(countrysheet.getCell(0, 2).getContents())+ " existing"); 
    String clickcountry = (countrylist.get(cui).getText());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement clickselected=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@span,'"+clickcountry+"')]"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    clickselected.click();
    
      }

Comment: Also I have tried this: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(clickcountry.toString()));
element.click(); but no use

Comment: Got it, I have used this: String clickcountry = (countrylist.get(cui).getText());
    
WebElement clickselected=new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(., \"" + clickcountry + "\")]")));
    
    clickselected.click();